# SQL: Insert into temp table on nested common table expression

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to insert into temp table inside the nested CTE as on below code. I can select from first x inside second expression but cannot insert into temp table.

```
WITH x AS 
    (
        SELECT * FROM MyTable
    ), 
    y AS 
    (
        SELECT * INTO #temp FROM x
    )
    SELECT * FROM y
```

I have to do this using nested CTE as there is other logic to implement. I know i can insert into temp table outside of expression. Is there a way to achieve this? Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server is quite explicit.  A query cannot both return a result set and save the results to a query.  You can easily do:

```
WITH x AS (
      SELECT * FROM MyTable
     )
SELECT x.*
INTO #temp
FROM x;
```

And then:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM #temp t;
```

The first query saves the result set into a temporary table.  The second returns the values from the query.

Comment: I mentioned that i know that it can be done outside of expression. But i  have to do this inside nested expression because of other logic. i was wondering if it is possible. Thank you for your quick resposne

Comment: I have accepted as there is no alternative way to do this and i have to do this without using nested CTE