# Nested SELECTs into #temp tables

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to do the following in MSSQL:

```
Select OrderNumber, StartDate, EndDate, DateDiff(hours, Date1, Date2) 
FROM (
    Select OrderNumber, MIN(Date1), MAX(Date2) INTO #TempTable WHERE ......
)
```

It doesnt seem to like the INTO the Temp table.  Is that a thing?

Comment: As far as concerned, the `INTO` part should belong the outer query. But why are you using a subquery in the first place? You would need to give an explanation of what you are trying to accomplish, possibly with sample data and expected results.

Comment: Question.  The `#TempTable`. is it used more than just this query? meaning if you fill it in this query, are there others in queue that use it? or is this a one time thing, and it goes away?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44520395/sql-insert-into-temp-table-on-nested-common-table-expression